# How can you make a function that returns a function in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

for an example, if a function receives a function as a factor and iterates it twice

func x = f(f(x))

I have totally no idea of how the code should be written

Comment: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/ocaml/, and a good way to progress is to write small programs as you learn (https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/up_and_running.html)

Answer (score 2):

You just pass the function as a value. E.g.:

```
let apply_twice f x = f (f x)
```

should do what you expect. We can try it out by testing on the command line:

```
utop # apply_twice ((+) 1) 100
- : int = 102
```

The `(+) 1` term is the function that adds one to a number (you could also write it as `(fun x -> 1 + x)`). Also remember that a function in OCaml does not need to be evaluated with all its parameters. If you evaluate `apply_twice` only with the function you receive a new function that can be evaluated on a number:

```
utop # let add_two = apply_twice ((+) 1) ;;
val add_two : int -> int = <fun>
utop # add_two 1000;;
- : int = 1002
```

Answer (score 1):

To provide a better understanding: In OCaml, functions are first-class
values. Just like `int` is a value, `'a -> 'a -> 'a` is a value (I
suppose you are familiar with function signatures). So, how do you
implement a function that returns a function? Well, let's rephrase it:
As functions = values in OCaml, we could phrase your question in three
different forms:
**[1]** a function that returns a function
**[2]** a function that returns a value
**[3]** a value that returns a value

Note that those are all equivalent; I just changed terms.
**[2]** is probably the most intuitive one for you.

First, let's look at how OCaml evaluates functions (concrete example):

```
let sum x y = x + y
(val sum: int -> int -> int = <fun>)
```

f takes in two int's and returns an int (Intuitively speaking, a
functional value is a value, that can evaluate further if you provide
values). This is the reason you can do stuff like this:

```
let partial_sum = sum 2
(int -> int = <fun>)


let total_sum = partial_sum 3 (equivalent to: let total_sum y = 3 + y)
(int = 5)
```

`partial_sum` is a function, that takes in only one `int` and returns
another `int`. So we already provided one argument of the function,
now one is still missing, so it's still a functional value. If that is
still not clear, look into it more. (Hint: `f x = x` is equivalent to
`f = fun x -> x`) Let's come back to your question. The simplest
function, that returns a function is the function itself:

```
let f x = x 
(val f:'a -> 'a = <fun>)
f 
('a -> 'a = <fun>)
```

let f x = x Calling f without arguments returns f itself.  Say you
wanted to concatenate two functions, so `f o g`, or `f(g(x))`:

```
let g x = (* do something *)
(val g: 'a -> 'b)
let f x = (* do something *)
(val f: 'a -> 'b)
let f_g f g x = f (g x)
(val f_g: ('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b = <fun>)
```

`('a -> 'b)`: that's `f`, `('c -> 'a)`: that's `g`, `c`: that's x.

**Exercise**: Think about why the particular signatures have to be like that.  Because `let f_g f g x = f (g x)` is equivalent to `let f_g = fun f -> fun g -> fun x -> f (g x)`, and we do **not** provide
the argument x, we have created a function concatenation. Play around
with providing partial arguments, look at the signature, and there
will be nothing magical about functions returning functions;  or:
functions returning values.

Comment: Can't figure out, how to post it without getting the error "our post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code". So I posted it as a quote :/

Comment: Seems to have worked for me - could you check if it is what you want? I believe the references got lost though.

Comment: Yes, thanks :)!